# Opposite of "prequel" when it isn't a "sequel", or an "original"

Tags: vocabulary

How do you refer to an item that was released earlier, but takes place after a "prequel"?

"Sequel" gives the clear implication that it was released after, this is not what I want.

In some cases "Original" applies, but that only works if the [word I want] was the first. Which isn't always the case.

For example:

"Caprica" is a prequel series to the "Battlestar Galactica" reboot released circa 2005.

But when talking about "Caprica", you can't just refer to that specific earlier work as the original "Battlestar Galactica", because the original was released in 1978, and Caprica isn't really a prequel to the original.

Another Example:

"Lego City Undercover: The Chase Begins" is a prequel to the "Lego City Undercover" game for the Wii U, in this case "Original" probably refers to the aforementioned Wii U game, but might refer to the first Lego City game, or the first modern Lego, one could say "The original Lego City Undercover", but it is quite wordy, and due to the similarities in name might be a little confusing.

Comment: In cases where "original" won't do, consider similar terms like "previous installment" or "earlier work."

Comment: @BraddSzonye Both of those are a little ambiguous, and are only cleaned up by becoming more wordy "the previous installment of the Lego City Undercover series", and I'm trying to reference said work quickly, without saying the whole name.

Comment: Caprica **is** a prequel. Just like Star Wars I, II and III are prequels. *Prequel* refers to the position in the overall storyline, and actually appears to refer more often to earlier parts which were released after the "original" (like Star Wars).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not trying to refer to Caprica, I'm trying to refer to the 2005ish series within the context of Caprica. i.e. "You really liked Caprica? I didn't like Caprica as much as [the thing that it was prequeling (which is what I want a word for)]".

Comment: Well, you obviously know what you're talking about, but there are too many "prequel", "not really a prequel", "earlier work", "original" and "aforementioned" for me. I'm terminally confused. But it is late.

Comment: There are two time dimensions at play in this context, the release times, and the plot-line times, so why not just reference the dimension you are describing.... Star Wars episode 4 is the "plot sequel" to episode 3. 'Retronym' is an interesting neologism that seems to have a very appropriate wiki entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym specifically mentioning the Star Wars franchise. I think, in this culture, inventing a word is appropriate. How about the 'preneoquel', or justthe 'presequel'

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think McKay is looking for a word pair like _protegé–mentor_ or _parent–child_ that describes both ends of the sequel/prequel relationship. _Child_ is to _parent_ as _sequel/prequel_ is to ...? _Original_ is typical but ambiguous in the case of remakes and reboots.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That is correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yeah, I have to use "earlier work", and other words, because such a word doesn't exist. The article would read a lot better if I actually had a word to describe such a work.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, after commenting (above), I searched, and 'pre-sequel' appears to be a commonly used term for these types of situation. Episode 4 is the pre-sequel to Episode 3 (and 2 and 1).

Comment: Do you have an example using this in the sense you mean? I'm not very familiar with this word, but it appears to refer more to works like _Attack of the Clones_ that are sequels to a prequel.